# unfortunately,android has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-emulator

iam new here and i want to find some solutions.everytime i click the login button i   always have a error that tells "unfortunately,
 android has stopped" i cant think of any errors i have.

> First.java

```
    package com.example.android;

            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.view.Menu;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
            import android.widget.*;
            import android.content.Intent;




            public class First extends Activity {

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.firstlayout);
                    Button admin = (Button) findViewById (R.id.admin);
                    admin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){




                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent it = new Intent (First.this, Secondadmin.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                    System.exit(0);

                }

                    });

                    Button sec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sec);
                    sec.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent is = new Intent(First.this, Secondsec.class);
                            startActivity(is);
                            System.exit(0);
                        }

                    });

                    Button stock = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stock);
                    stock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent iu= new Intent(First.this,Secondstock.class);
                            startActivity(iu);
                            System.exit(0);
                        }

                    });

                }


                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
                    return true;
                }

            }
```

> firstlayout.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/widget32"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/admin"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ADMIN" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sec"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SECRETARY" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stock"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CHECKERS" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

> Secondadmin.java

```
 package com.example.android;



        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.widget.Button;

        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;


        public class Secondadmin extends Activity {

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.secondlayout);

                 Button login= (Button) findViewById (R.id.login);
                    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            {    

                                 Intent log = new Intent(Secondadmin.this, Thirdadmin.class);
                                 startActivity(log);
                            }
                        }
                        });




                Button exit = (Button) findViewById (R.id.exit);
                exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Secondadmin.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");

                        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {


                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                Secondadmin.this.finish();
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        });

                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                AlertDialog alert= builder.create();
                alert.show();
                }});
                     Button back= (Button) findViewById (R.id.back);
                     back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent is = new Intent (Secondadmin.this, First.class);
                             startActivity(is);
                         }
                });

        }

        }
```

> secondlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="91dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Password" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Back" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Exit" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

> Thirdadmin.java

```
 package com.example.android;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


        public class Thirdadmin extends Activity {

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.thirdlayoutadmin);

                Button view= (Button)findViewById(R.id.view);
                view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    Intent id= new Intent(Thirdadmin.this, Fourthview.class);
                    startActivity(id);

                }
            });
                Button update= (Button)findViewById(R.id.update);
                update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    Intent i= new Intent(Thirdadmin.this, Fourthupdate.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });

                Button add= (Button) findViewById (R.id.add);
                add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            Intent it= new Intent(Thirdadmin.this, Fourthadmin.class);
                            startActivity(it);
                        }

                    });

                Button delete= (Button) findViewById (R.id.delete);
                delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent t= new Intent(Thirdadmin.this, Fourthdelete.class);
                        startActivity(t);
                    }

                });
                Button exit = (Button) findViewById (R.id.exit);
                exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Thirdadmin.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");

                        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {


                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                Thirdadmin.this.finish();
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        });

                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                AlertDialog alert= builder.create();
                alert.show();
                }});
                     Button back= (Button) findViewById (R.id.back);
                     back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent is = new Intent (Thirdadmin.this, Secondadmin.class);
                             startActivity(is);
                         }
                });


                }   

            }
```

> thirdlayoutadmin.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="View" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/update"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Update" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Delete"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

> android:manifest

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.android"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.android.First"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".Secondadmin"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                </activity>

            <activity 
                android:name=".Secondsec"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                </activity>
            <activity 
                android:name=".Secondstock"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                </activity>
                <activity 
                android:name=".Thirdsec"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                </activity>
                 <activity 
                android:name=".Thirdstock"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                </activity>
                 <activity 
                android:name=".Thirdadmin"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                </activity>
                <activity
                android:name=".Fourthadmin"
                android:label="@string/app_name">     
                </activity>
                <activity
                android:name=".Fourthstock"
                android:label="@string/app_name">     
                </activity>
                <activity
                android:name=".Fourthdelete"
                android:label="@string/app_name"> 
                </activity>
                <activity
                android:name=".Fourthview"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

everytime i click the login button i always have a error that tells "unfortunately, android has stopped" i cant think of any errors i have.

LogCat:

```
04-15 02:29:54.553: W/dalvikvm(790): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.Thirdadmin}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at com.example.android.Thirdadmin.onCreate(Thirdadmin.java:73)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-15 02:29:54.603: E/AndroidRuntime(790):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: can you provide the logcat messages you get the app exits unexpectedly? you can see those messages in a window titled "Logcat" in Eclipse, or you can gather them by typing "adb logcat" in a terminal.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Only post the code in question and not the whole app. Also to be able to help you it would be great if you could post the stacktrace.

Comment: Why are you using system.exit(0)?  Do not try to "quit" your app.  Let Android take care of app management and navigation.

Comment: if you really want to quit your screen then call finish() method which will close the current activity

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `System.exit(0);`. Use `finish()` instead.